# is there any way to move myentity.orm.yml files out of a Symfony bundle?

Tags: orm, doctrine, config

I have a unusual situation where I have to keep all myBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/*.orm.yml files out of the bundle.

My question is how we can save the file somewhere else (i.e in the root of src/ folder) and let the doctrine know about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the location of orm files, I believe you have to inform this to Symfony core, which can be a painful thing. The given possible place is under bundle `resources\doctrine` location.

Comment: Thanks Anjana but you just repeated the facts I've mentioned already. Do you know how to inform Symfony about the location of *.orm.yml config files?